measurability of a special set
I've been working on some questions in dynamical systems then I faced the following problem:
Consider the circle $\mathbb{T}^1:= \frac{\mathbb{R}}{\mathbb{Z}}$. We represent it as a union of disjoint subsegments $M_{j}=[t_{j}, t_{j+1})$, $j=0,\cdots,n, t_0 = t_n$ and define the map $S$ by the formula \begin{align*} S(t)= t + c_j \quad \text{mod} 1, \qquad t \in M_j \end{align*} Here $c_j$ are real values. Such map is called interval translation (ITM) or, if it is one-to-one it is called interval exchange (IEM).
We say that the ITM $S$ is finite type if there exists a number $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
S^m(\mathbb{T}^1)= \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} S^k(\mathbb{T}^1)
\end{align*}
Otherwise, the map $S$ is infinite type.
The followings have been already proved:

Every ITM admits Borel, probability, invariant, non-atomic measures. (A measure $\mu$ is invariant under the map $S$ if for any measurable subset A we have : $\mu(S^{-1}(A))= \mu(A) )$

For an ITM the cardinality of inverse of every singleton is finite. the means if $x \in T^1$ then $|S^{-1}({x})|< \infty$

Suppose $S$ is an ITM and $\mu$ is the Borel Probability invariant non atomic measure for $S$ then recurrent poinst of $S$ is dense in support of $\mu$.

If $S$ is an interval translation map then for any Borel measurable subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{T}^1$, $S(A)$ is Borel measurable set.


The problem I've been working on is that every ITM is invertible almost everywhere on the support of its invariant measure. I proved that each ITM is surjective a.e. on the support of its invariant measure. ($S(\mathbb{T}^1)=\mathbb{T}^1$ a.e.).
It remained that I prove every ITM is injective almost everywhere.
For this I have tried this:
Just imagine $y$ is a point in $S(T^1)$ so $|S^{-1}(y)|$ is either 1 or more than 1.
If $|S^{-1}(y)|=1$, for example $z$ is the only point which $S(z)= y$, we put $z$ in a set named $A$.
If $|S^{-1}(y)| >1$, for example $|S^{-1}(y)| =2$, and $w,r$ are the only points which $S(w)=S(r)=y$, we put only one point between $w$ and $r$ in the set $A$.
This process goes on for all points in $S(T^1)$ for any arbitrary cardinal of $|S^{-1}(y)|$.
Then $A$ is constructed the way $S$ is injective on and $S(A)$ is exactly the image of $T^1$.
We put all other points (Other points of $S^{-1}(y)$ except the one in $A$) in a set named $B$. So $\mathbb{T}^1= A \dot{\cup} B$, then:
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{T}^1 = A \dot{\cup} B &\Rightarrow \mathbb{T}^1= S^{-1}(\mathbb{T}^1)= S^{-1}(A) \dot{\cup} S^{-1}(B)\\
    &\Rightarrow \mu(\mathbb{T}^1)= \mu(S^{-1}(A))+ \mu(S^{-1}(B))=\mu(A)+\mu(B)
\end{align*}
Notice that $S$ on $A$ is both injective and surjective, so $\mu(A)=\mu(S(A))=\mu(S(\mathbb{T}^1))=\mu(\mathbb{T}^1)=1$, then $\mu(B)=0$.\
If I check that $A$ and $B$ are measurable the problem is solved.
For this, I already checked that
$ A_n= \{ x \in S^1 \mid |S^{-1}(x)|= n \} $
is measurable. (See Abstract transverse measure theory )
Now my questions is that :
From $S(\mathbb{T}^1)= \mathbb{T}^1$ a.e. could I conclude that for any ITM the measure of overlaping parts is zero?
Could you help me show $A$ or $B$ is measurable?
